# Programmatically obtain name of domain GAE application is hosted at?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it possible to programmatically obtain name of domain GAE application is hosted at ?

It's written in Java.

Comment: Note that when a servlet is invoked you can get the URL used from the request context.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if the url is not rewritten by some weird proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the library **identity**. Follow [this link](http://code.google.com/intl/eo/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/overview.html). You only need to run `ApiProxy.Environment.getAppId()` to get the firstpart.appspot.com :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than the subdomain, or you can't determine the rest of your server name from that, you need to read it from a servlet request.